# What happens when numerically approximating the gradient of a function at a nondifferentiable point?

Tags: numerical-methods, vector-analysis, finite-differences, subgradient

I am asking myself this question: Can anything be said of the resulting gradient, when the gradient of a function is approximated numerically (for example using the finite differences method) at a nondifferentiable point?

Could this result in any number? For example, when considering a convex function, will this always approximate some subgradient?

I wasn't able to find anything on this question, is the answer totally obvious?

Comment: As with the case in 1 dimension, you typically get something similar to the average gradient around that point, also equal to the gradient at some nearby point (see multi-dimensional mean value theorem).

Comment: The issue is that you might get results that have simply no significance. Consider the continuous absolute values function$f(x) = \vert x \vert$ at $x= 0$. Using central finite differences, $$f'(x)\Big \vert_0 \approx \frac{f(0 + h  - f (0 - h)}{2h} = \frac{h - h}{2h} = 0.$$
How would you interpret this?